# OpenAM: RESTFUL API - Encrypt/Encode Password

Tags: openam

We are using the Open AM Restful API to perform authentication. Our restful call has the following format:

http://OpenAM_Host:Port/deploy_uri/identity/authenticate?username=scott&password=tiger

How can we send the password in an encrypted/encoded format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently out of the box, you need to implement an 
own DataStore (if you use the DataStore auth module) or an authentication module which will use symmetric decryption on the supplied password.

Answer (score 1):

You could also enable HTTPBasic Auth module on a chain and send the username/value pair base64 encoded. Not encrypted, but encoded at least (along with special character support).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, OpenAM does not provide this support out of the box. Based on information from the OpenAM mailing list, there are two options:

Option 1. SSL and POST
The most common solution is to make use of SSL for encryption.

Option 2. Custom Login Module
If you need to encrypt your password with a given algorithm, then you will need to create a custom login module. You will encrypt the password before making the restful call and then the login module with decrypt the password. In this scenario, you do not need SSL.